# Regexp to change form of a phone number

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to change a phone number format by using a regular expression. The following example shows what the original format is and how it should be changed:

> (216) 765 8765 ---> Phone: 216-7658765

I tried using the following code:

```
data = data.replaceAll("([0-9]{3})|([\\s\\./0-9])*$","$1"+"-"+"$2");
```

but it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Try it like this using 3 capturing groups `\\(([0-9]+)\\)\\h+([0-9]+)\\h+([0-9]+)` and replace with `$1-$2$3` https://regex101.com/r/WjEcPI/1

Comment: Your `*` isn’t inside the capturing group. You’re only capturing a single character. You’re also not replacing spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexp is wrong :) You should get some compilation errors about bad escape sequences.

So first your errors:

- your first match for the (216) was technically correct, but in order
  to get the the () to drop, you also need to match inside those: `\(([0-9]{3})\)`
- your second match was all kind of bungled :) First, if you're going to use \s in a String, most languages will think you want to Escape "s". So most of the times you need to escape the \ itself. so \s
- i have no idea what the pipe | is for, but you can just make it a space.

Working example:

```
data.replaceAll("\\(([0-9]{3})\\) ([\\s0-9]+)*$","$1-$2")
```

https://code.sololearn.com/cVRUy2BwauK8#java

Comment: I think that would return `216-765 8765` instead of `216-7658765`

Comment: I understood what you explained here but I still get the initial input on my output :(

Edit: I'm a dummy it works thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't invent the wheel, unless you really want to. Have a look at this lib
https://github.com/google/libphonenumber